# Teen sci-fi written before 2003 - body upgrade, synthetic bodies?

Tags: story-identification, cyborg

I am trying desperately to remember the title and author of a science fiction book for teenagers, written before 2003.

The book was about a young adult virgin who sold her physical body to have an upgrade to a synthetic body. Her "sponsor" (buyer), was the CEO/Owner of the company that made the synthetic bodies so she ended up having a **top-of-the line trial body**, instead of the cheap one she had payed for.

While in recuperation she is rooming with or becomes friends with another girl from a rich family who paid for her to have the same body as she was previously either paraplegic or quadriplegic.

I think it was set in the far distant future, however I for the life of me can't remember much more than the info I've given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe *[Spare Parts](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2886961-spare-parts)*.

Description from [author's website](http://www.sallyrogersdavidson.com/spare-parts-universe.html):

> C-grade citizen of the Greater Melbourne Megalopolis, Kelty lives in a city filled with towers reaching halfway to the sky. While ‘Skywalkers’, the A- and B-grade citizens live above the clouds with access to all the wonders of the late 21st century, ‘Subbies’ like Kelty must dwell in the shadows and smog of the streets below.
>
> When her best friend is horribly injured in an explosion at the recycle plant where they both work, Kelty is faced with the loss of a friend and a hopeless future, or the unthinkable choice of leaving everyone and everything behind to join the Space Corps. There’s just one catch - first she must trade in her human body for a State-of-the-Art Cyboform.

Comment: could you flesh this answer out why it matches that story

Comment: I honestly don't know if it's a good match, but this is most likely "Spare Parts" I could find.

Comment: OHMYGOSH!!!!!!! That is the book!!!!! Thank you thank you thank you!!!!

I had completely forgotten that I posted in here, hence the very very late response. 

I had my two younger brothers googling for this book for me for freaking MONTHS as well as myself, and now I know what it is!!!!

Thank youuuuuu!!!!!

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Are you the answerer? If so, do you need an account merge?

Comment: @wizzwizz4: I am not. I was just trying to improve the answer at the time. Since it was almost three years ago, I can't really say why I thought it was likely to be that particular one, but apparently I guessed correctly.